# what is the equivalent of a group (like in office suites)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to group nodes in regard to positioning and to basic style

example: https://www.latex4technics.com?note=zzvqs6

```tex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,positioning,calc,shapes.multipart} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(D) {abcdefg};
        %
        \node (S1) {5};
        \node[right=0pt of S1] (S2) {6};
        \node[right=0pt of S2] (S3) {7};
        \node[right=0pt of S3] (S4) {8};
        \node[fit=(S1)(S2)(S3)(S4),below=0pt of D,font=\bfseries,fill=gray!20](g1){};
        %
        \node[fit=(g1)(D),text width=50,inner sep=0pt](l){};
        %
        \node[right=0pt of l,text width=150] (T) {cccc};
        %
        \node[fit=(T)(l),inner sep=0pt](top){};
        \node[below=0pt of top,text width=200] (B) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node[below=0pt of B,text width=200] (Q) {bbbbbbbbbbbbb};
        \node[fit=(top)(B)(Q),inner sep=0pt,rounded corners](E){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. the nodes s1-s4  are not "below=0pt of A" (the fill gray is though)
2. the nodes s1-s4 are not bfseries'ed

the idea is to get something like that:

```
        ┌─────────┬───────┐
        │ abcdefg │       │
        │         │ccccc  │
        │ 5 6 7 8 │       │
        ├─────────┴───────┤
        │    aaaaaaaaaa   │
        │                 │
        │    bbbbbbbbbb   │
        │                 │
        └─────────────────┘
```

i.e.

- nodes 5 6 7 8 centered under abcdefg
- cccc vertically centered right of the abcdefg/5678 group
- the above with colored background
- a+ centered below the head
- b+ below a+
- everything put into a box with rounded corners

Comment: OK but what is the point of your question? What do you want to achieve knowing that? It's not clear what you want to put into these nodes. You could use a matrix of nodes, for example, but you have to be more specific. The code you provided is wrong: the line `\node[fit=(S1)(S2)(S3)(S4),below=0pt of D,font=\bfseries,fill=gray!20](g1){};` does not specify nodes S1 to S4 to be bold, but creates another node named g1 below of D, fitting S1 to S4 (see what `fit` does), and with no content (so the `\bfseries` is useless here).

Comment: You can use a local bounding box name with a scope.  You can put tikzpictures into saveboxes and put the saveboxes into nodes.

Comment: thx for your support. I want to create a kind of parameterized object where the strings given above are variable. Fit is in deed not the right thing (i thought of it as a way of grouping nodes). i think saveboxes/scopes have no way of parameterization, do they?

Comment: In the contrary, `scope` allows you to parametrize almost everything, you just put your parameters into brackets after declaration: `\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,line width=2pt}]`, etc.